# MYSQL became unresponsive after some time (In my case 30 mins) on high load (400 concurrent thread per hour)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

I am doing load testing on my application using `MySQL` server for the same. Here I am putting load of 400 users per hour for doing something on application. I have done some `MySQL` tuning at `my.conf` file.

I am using one application server (4GB RAM with dual core processor) and one database server (4GB RAM with dual core processor) and `MySQL` version is `5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2-log` (Ubuntu).

Here are my settings:

```
bind-address            = *
max_connect_errors=10000
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 200
max_user_connections   = 100
table_open_cache       = 1000
table_definition_cache = 1000
tmp_table_size         = 256M
flush_time             = 0
key_buffer              = 64M
max_allowed_packet      = 32M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 16M
back_log                = 1000
query_cache_limit       = 64M
query_cache_size        = 128M
connect_timeout         = 15
interactive_timeout     = 300
wait_timeout            = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2048MB
innodb_io_capacity=1000
innodb_read_io_threads=8
innodb_write_io_threads=8
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=16M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 300
log_slow_queries=ON
long_query_time=3.000000
query_cache_type=OFF
slow_query_log=ON
log_output=TABLE
open_files_limit = 4000
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M
```

One more point for about 30 mins when I see processlist it show me 13-20 connections but suddenly after 30 mins it increase to 140 and server become to unresponsive please help me to get rid from this.

Comment: What do your logs say. Run mysqltuner.

Comment: Probably your queries executed too slow. Queries arrive faster than server can process them. So you get a jam, when queries waits in the queue, and processing rate is lower than arrival rate. Such situation have well distinguished symptom - everything is all right under the low load, but when load arise everything immediately falls down. What you have to do - is to read slow queries log.